# Adding headers to only certain calls in Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to set up Swagger for our API using Swashbuckle. Every one of our controllers inherits from a BaseController that has ~8 parameters(userId, language, platform, etc) on it. They each have read only variables with their get function set to read the value from the headers pulled in. Ex:

```
protected int UserID
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["user_Id"]);
        }
    }
```

When I first installed Swagger, it would only give options to pass in parameters that are listed in the method. Those parameters always exclude the ~8 parameters that are set in BaseController, so if a controller uses the user ID, the user ID isn't listed in the method signature. As user ID, won't show up on the Swagger-generated UI.

Right now, I've been experimenting using the SwaggerOperation attribute like so:

```
[SwaggerOperation("UserValidate(UserID)")]
    public int UserValidate()
    {
            return this._UserValidateService.UserValidate(this.UserID);
```

And I have a custom swagger parameter that checks all of the methods if their SwaggerOperation name contains "UserID", and if so add the UserID header to that call.

My problem with this is that I have to manually go through every call and add the swagger operation, and if the call ever changes, we have to remember to also change the SwaggerOperation.

I also thought about just adding the 8 to every API call and marking them as optional, but that sounds like it would bloat the UI horribly.

Please advise on the situation. Are there options I haven't considered? Are they Swashbuckle functionalities I've missed that will fix my issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using swashbuckle>=5, you can add operation filter as below. It will add a header to only selected requests:

```
public class AddHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod.Equals("POST") && context.ApiDescription.RelativePath.Contains("login"))
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "UserId",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "String",
                },
                Required = true
            });
        }

    }
```

Above adds a required header t only POST operation which has action name as login.